# Page crashing from '#' as a GET-parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, get

Ive been using URL-parameters to make a landingpage behind a searchform more personal. I felt *relatively* bulletproof validating stuff like this

```
$string = $_GET['city']
$res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $string);
```

until I tried something like ?city=# as a value and my whole page crashed and im not so sure anymore.

What is the way to go to validate without writing a whole engine or at least stop my page crashing from #?

Thanks

Comment: you gotta escape it. an unescaped `#` in an url marks the local part that's *not* sent to the server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP has a lot of functionalities which help you avoid problems like this.
Whenever you create URL to be displayed in the browser it has to be [urlencoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). If you are just appending the query string part to a fixed url you can build that string with [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). For example:

```
$querystring = [
    'param1' = 123,
    'param2' = 'hello with a #'
];
$QS_encoded = http_build_query($querystring);
echo '<a href="?'.$QS_encoded.'">My link</a>';
```

`#` in URL denotes another part of URL which is the hash part. This is not going to be a part of your `$_GET` superglobal.

If for any reason you would like to type out the URL with a query string containing `#` manually by hand, then you need to use the encoded version `%23`. e.g. http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%23

On a side note. You shouldn't use regex for filtering data like this. PHP once again has already an extension for this: [filters](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

Comment: I see a downvote, but there is no explanation what is wrong with my answer. Could someone care to explain, please?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanaiton, helped me a lot. No idea who voted that down. As im pretty new im not able to vote you up again - sorry.